Find the first occurrence by date of a value from a list of values for each ID in a table
I have a table of data from Azure DevOps that contains a sequence of status changes for work items. Each record contains an ID for the work item, a status, a date at which the status changed and a date on which the work item was created.
I am attempting to calculate SLA compliance by measuring the number of days between a work item being created and then subsequently reaching one of a set of potential status values. I then need to check if the number of days is more or less than 7.
In my table, I have already added a calculated column that holds the number of days between the created date and the status change date for each record.
I am now trying to add a further calculated column to identify the first occurrence of each work item ID reaching one of a specific set of status values. I then want to flag those records as being used for the SLA calculation.
Please can anyone assist me with the DAX code for finding the first occurrence of one of a set of statuses for each ID in the table? The image below shows a sample of the data.

Thanks in advance.

In power query could you right click and reference your query and then in this new query filter to your desired specific set of status values and then group by the work item id, title, and use the MIN operation dropdown on your state change date. Then merge this with your original query?

Thanks for the response, please could you provide example code for how I would filter for the specific statuses I am looking for?

If you edit the query in power query then you can use the filters at the top of the headers in that new query I mentioned. This creates a subset of your data on those filters. Then when you merge this back to the first query it will filter based on that merge.

is this what you want
Column2=
MAXX (
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        'Table'[Work Item Id] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Work Item Id] )
            && 'Table'[Status Change Date] = 'Table'[Created Date]
    ),
    'Table'[Status]
)



Hi, thanks for the response. This looks like part of what I need.
However, I need to filter the results so that it only applies to a subset of statuses.
New, Impact Assessment and On Hold would not be included. I need to find the first occurrence of any of the following statuses for each Work Item ID:
Backlog,
Sponsor Approval,
Rejected
Thanks,

pls provide the sample data in table, not the screenshot and the expected output based on the sample data you provided
